# Why async move is not moving the two structs here?

Tags: rust, async-await

Using the below code I'm getting the error:

```
cargo build
   Compiling playground v0.1.0 (/home/explorer/playground)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `config`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:50:26
   |
36 |   pub fn execute_jobs(config: Arc<Config>) {
   |                       ------ captured outer variable
...
49 |               .with_run_async(Box::new(|_, _| {
   |                                        ------ captured by this `FnMut` closure
50 |                   Box::pin(async move {
   |  __________________________^
51 | |                     println!("run async every 2 seconds");
52 | |
53 | |                     do_job(&config.first, settings).await.unwrap();
   | |                             ------
   | |                             |
   | |                             variable moved due to use in coroutine
   | |                             move occurs because `config` has type `Arc<Config>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
54 | |                 })
   | |_________________^ `config` is moved here
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

and another for `settings` of course.

I don't understand why, since I'm using the `async move`. I cannot understand the error either.

The code is "very simple" ([here a REPL too](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/6zc27e)):

```rust
use std::{sync::Arc, time::Duration};
use tokio_cron_scheduler::{JobBuilder, JobScheduler};

struct Config {
    first: String,
    second: String,
}

struct Settings {
    first: String,
    second: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let config = Config {
        first: "first".to_string(),
        second: "second".to_string(),
    };

    execute_jobs(Arc::new(config));

    // Simulate server in background
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(120)).await;
}

pub fn execute_jobs(config: Arc<Config>) {
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        let settings = Settings {
            first: "first".to_string(),
            second: "second".to_string(),
        };

        let scheduler = JobScheduler::new().await.unwrap();

        let job = JobBuilder::new()
            .with_cron_job_type()
            .with_schedule("*/2 * * * * *")
            .unwrap()
            .with_run_async(Box::new(|_, _| {
                Box::pin(async move {
                    println!("run async every 2 seconds");

                    do_job(&config.first, settings).await.unwrap();
                })
            }))
            .build()
            .unwrap();

        scheduler.add(job).await.unwrap();

        scheduler.start().await.unwrap();
    });
}

async fn do_job(first_config: &str, settings: Settings) -> Result<(), ()> {
    dbg!(first_config);

    dbg!(settings.second);

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to the following:

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::Arc;
pub fn execute_jobs(config: Arc<String>) -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>> {
    Box::new(|| {
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("run async every 2 seconds {config}");
        })
    })
}
```

and the problem is that the `with_run_async` takes a parameter of type `Box<dyn FnMut(Uuid, JobsSchedulerLocked) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>> + Send + Sync>` so the closure you pass to it has to be able to be called multiple times (`FnMut`), but your closure tries to move `config` into the `Future` it returns, after the first call there would be no `config` left to be returned. You can just clone the `config` before you pass it to the `async move` block:

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::Arc;
pub fn execute_jobs(config: Arc<String>) -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>> {
    Box::new(|| {
        let config = Arc::clone(&config);
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("run async every 2 seconds {config}");
        })
    })
}
```